# Make libclang correctly parse headers of a Bazel project included with a relative path

Tags: python, parsing, bazel, libclang

Suppose I have a Bazel project with this structure:

```
WORKSPACE
- includes
    - a.h
    - BUILD
- includes_b
    - b.h
    - BUILD
```

with the following files:

`includes/BUILD`

```
cc_library(
    name = "a",
    srcs = [],
    hdrs = [
        "a.h",
    ],
    deps = [],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)
```

`includes/a.h`

```
struct A{
  public:
  int val;
};
```

`includes_b/BUILD`

```
cc_library(
    name = "b",
    srcs = [],
    hdrs = [
        "b.h",
    ],
    deps = ["//includes:a"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)
```

`includes_b/b.h`

```
#include "includes/a.h"

struct B{
  public:
  int val2;
  A a;
};
```

I am using linclang in Python to parse C++ source code: my script is the following:

```
import clang.cindex
import typing


def traverse(node, output_struct, file_parsed):
    print(node.spelling, node.kind)
    if node.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.STRUCT_DECL:
        if node.semantic_parent.spelling != "std":
            print("struct", node.spelling, "; parent: ",
                  node.semantic_parent.spelling)
            if node.semantic_parent.spelling == file_parsed:
                traverse.current_namespace = ""
            output_struct[node.spelling] = {
                "type": "struct",
                "attributes": [],
                "namespace": traverse.current_namespace
            }
    elif node.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.CLASS_DECL:
        if node.semantic_parent.spelling != "std":
            print("class", node.spelling, "; parent: ",
                  node.semantic_parent.spelling)
    elif node.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.ENUM_DECL:
        if node.semantic_parent.spelling != "std":
            print("field", node.spelling, "; parent: ",
                  node.semantic_parent.spelling)
            if node.semantic_parent.spelling == file_parsed:
                traverse.current_namespace = ""
        output_struct[node.spelling] = {
            "type": "enum",
            "attributes": [],
            "namespace": traverse.current_namespace
        }
    elif node.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.ENUM_CONSTANT_DECL:
        if node.semantic_parent.spelling != "std":
            print("enum_const", node.spelling, "; enum value: ",
                  node.enum_value, "; parent: ", node.semantic_parent.spelling)
        output_struct[node.semantic_parent.spelling]["attributes"].append(
            (node.spelling, node.enum_value))

    elif node.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.NAMESPACE:
        print("namespace", node.spelling, "; parent: ",
              node.semantic_parent.spelling)
        if node.semantic_parent.spelling == file_parsed:
            traverse.current_namespace = node.spelling
        elif node.semantic_parent.spelling == traverse.current_namespace:
            traverse.current_namespace += "::" + node.spelling
    elif node.kind == clang.cindex.CursorKind.FIELD_DECL:
        # enum_type, enum_value, semantic_parent, lexical_parent
        if node.semantic_parent.spelling != "std":
            print("field declaration", node.spelling, node.type.spelling,
                  "; parent: ", node.semantic_parent.spelling)
        if node.semantic_parent.spelling in output_struct.keys():  # fpos not found
            output_struct[node.semantic_parent.spelling]["attributes"].append(
                (node.spelling, node.type.spelling))
    print("+++++++++++++++++Sons of " + node.spelling +"+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
    for child in node.get_children():
        print(child.spelling)
    print("+++++++++++++++++++++END SONS+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
    for child in node.get_children():
        traverse(child, output_struct=output_struct, file_parsed=file_parsed)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
    file_parsed = "/absolute/path/clang_test/includes_b/b.h"
    parsed_struct = {}
    translation_unit = index.parse(
        file_parsed, args=['-x', 'c++', '-std=c++14'])
    traverse(translation_unit.cursor, parsed_struct, file_parsed)
    print(parsed_struct)
```

The problem is the following: the `a` attribute of struct `B`, instead of being recognised as `A` type, is regognised as `int` type, because apparently types unrecognised by clang are by default `int`.

The problem is that within the Bazel project, relative paths are used, so clang is unable to locate the header `a.h` parsing the file `b.h`. Prove of this is the fact that if I change the include with the absolute path, then everything works and `a` is recognised as of type `A` and also `a.h` is parsed.

How can I make libclang parse also the header `a.h` when analysing the `b.h` file? I was thinking to extract the working directory with `os.getcwd()` and then pre-pend it to the include string, but I cannot find the point where libclang analyse the include directory.

I have tried to use the `clang.cindex.CursorKind.INCLUSION_DIRECTIVE` but no node of this kind was defined.

How can I tell libclang where to search that header file?